# Swiper.js W3C AA keyboard tab issue

Tags: accessibility, carousel, w3c, swiper.js

I have a requirement to make a carousel using Swiper.JS to be W3C AA compliant.

Issue i'm facing is if the tab each slider the slider gets broken, and the right arrow control is the middle of the carousel. Is there any way to automatically set the non visible slides with tabindex="-1" or make the visibility hidden, so its not possible to tab to them?

Comment: you just answered your own question, adjust the `tabindex` on the slides to be -1. As far as I am aware this isn't an accessible slider so you will have to change the code / create a plugin yourself that does this. There are methods for next slide, current slide etc. so writing this shouldn't be too tough. Is there anything else to this question that i am missing?